# How to convert m4v/mp4 video files to DVD format (VIDEO_TS folder)

Tags: mac, video, dvd

I'm wondering how I can convert iPhone videos into a format that I can use a burner such as LiquidCD to burn a VIDEO_TS folder onto a DVD. Preferably a tool that's simple and free (or at least inexpensive). Mac OS only.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With iDVD version 7 (the latest, not upgraded since iLife '08) you can drag an .m4v or .mp4 directly onto a project. This might even work with earlier versions (don't have any to test). Every Mac in recent memory should have a copy.

Not surprisingly, the videos don't play if bought through the iTunes Store.

Comment: No kidding! I'll have to try this out next time I have the chance (couple days or so). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Having trawled the net for suitable programs I have to agree that iDVD is about the best program for the job.  It has some good themes, can do transitions, allows custom text etc.
OK, it's a bit tricky if your DVD is longer than 2 hours (you might need some blank DL DVD's) and many of it's themes are a bit cheesy but there are one or two gems.

Try searching the net for extra themes. Not tried myself but I understand there are some add on's

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You had asked for "Simpler" -- the easiest one I found is Evom. It's drag and drop:

http://thelittleappfactory.com/evom/

Comment: Nice! I'll try this out as well, tonight.